# How to apply lambda converters to all the columns of the data in numpy.genfromtxt function

Tags: python, numpy

I have an buffer array (dimensions (1 by 3024)) in a text file and I want to store it as a numpy array. I have following line of code for reading the array:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("vertex_buffer.txt",delimiter=",", converters={0:lambda a: 1.0 if (abs(float(a))>MAX) else float(a),0: lambda a: 0.0 if (abs(float(a))<MIN) else float(a)})
```

I want to apply both the converters to all the columns in the data (number of columns is 3024 and number of row is 1 in the text file). A sample data from the text file is as follows:

```
0.013767980970442295,-0.01189893763512373,0.25876250863075256,-1.6123274974617568e-27,0.5568627715110779,0.615686297416687,0.7490196228027344,0.025758866220712662,-0.01189893763512373,0.18305502831935883,-4.4319408131327203e-16,0.5568627715110779,0.615686297416687,0.7490196228027344
```

From my understanding, either there is a syntax for applying converters to all the columns or there must be a way to treat the row in the text file as column and vice versa. But, could not find anything concrete from documentation. I am hoping for some help in this matter.

Comment: So - is the question how to apply the min and max functions, or is it about transposing the table to have a single column?

Comment: I actually want to apply min and max functions to all the values.

Comment: `converters` are good if you need to perform some special string manipulation, such as reading an odd date format.  But if all you are doing is fiddling with float values, it's better to let `genfromtxt` load those as floats, and use `numpy` array methods to tweak the values after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load up your data into a numpy array, then use the [numpy.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) function to apply the max and min bounds to the array.

```
new_array = np.clip(original_array, 0, 1)
```

Comment: You could possibly apply the `numpy.clip` function as a convertor as well.